# Why does "unter" mean both "under" and "among, between"?

Tags: etymology

What semantic notions underlie ["under" and "among, between"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/unter)? How are they semantically related?

The English cognate [under](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=under) doesn't mean "among, between".

Comment: An answer to the question can be found in a (presumably any) etymological dictionary of the German language. See eg Pfeifer, Etymologisches Wörterbuch, available through DWDS: https://www.dwds.de/wb/unter ("In dem gemeingerm. Wort ... sind in germ. Zeit zwei ursprünglich verschiedene Präpositionen zusammengefallen"); Kluge, Etymologisches Wörterbuch, 25th edn; Duden, Herkunftswörterbuch, 6th edn.

Comment: @johnl - It may be helpful to explain the origin in English. German etymological dictionaries tend to be full of arcane jargon and abbreviations, and are difficult for learners to decipher. There is an English translation of the entry for *unten* in Kluge on-line [here](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/An_Etymological_Dictionary_of_the_German_Language/Annotated/unten), but it only seems to mention one meaning.

Comment: There's really no reason to expect *unter* and "under" to have the same meanings. First, meaning of words drift over the centuries, so the modern meanings are often different in different languages. Second, prepositions in general are notoriously difficult to master and there is no direct correspondence between prepositions in different languages. Most prepositions have a number of meanings, and each meaning can translate to a different preposition in the other language.

Comment: @johnl - PS. According to Wiktionary, the Proto-Germanic *under* was the result of a merger of Proto-Indo-European prepositions *n̥dʰér* (under) and *n̥tér* (inside); is this the merger they are talking about in DWDS? If so then it took place before the split between English and German and the question should really be why did English lose the "inside" meaning rather than why did German gain it.

Comment: @RDBury So it is probably related to the Latin "inter" which means "among, between".

Comment: So it is all rather interesting after all then? Why not answer it?

Comment: Well, where do the words underwriter, undertaker, underage, and so on come from? You are talking about two different languages.

Comment: Why is "since" used in the two ways seen in "I have been here since Thursday", and "He can't be here, since he's in Mongolia"? In every language this kind of thing happens, but not with the same words in one language as in another.

Comment: @Paul Frost - Wiktionary's PIE explanations aren't always very clear, but it seems that yes, Latin *inter* and also *īnferus* (from which comes "inferior" and "infra-") are from the same PIE roots.

Comment: @RDBury, the notion of "root" tends to be often fallacious. The reconstructed stems \*n̥dʰér and \*n̥tér only have the \*n̥ in common, it seems. This is critical. The wiktionary explains 1. \*h₁n̥dʰér "\*h₁n̥dʰí (“under, below”) + \*-ér, \*-éri (innovative locative suffix) ..." 2. \*h₁n̥dʰí "Likely from \*h₁ní (“down, downwards”) +‎ \*dʰe (locative particle)" 3. \*h₁ní as \*h₁én (in zero grade with interconsonantal syllabification of \*n), so far so good, but then less detailed 4. \*h₁n̥tér "From \*h₁en" without attention to \*-tér. NB: a) \*dʰí is a "root" as much as *ein* in *((h(e))r)ein*

Comment: b) \*h₁ní (cp. *nieder* "down") is different from \*h₁en- "in", although it seems syllabified in either case. c) The \*h₁ is entirely theoretical and thought have been lost almost everywhere (after the n syllabified, the syllabification counting as evidence for former presence of a leading consonant; this is still debatable). 6. The list s. v. \*h₁en has a third derivation \*h₁én-teros (“inner, located inside”), a fourth \*h₁(e)n-dó (“inside”), and more, but carefully spells \*h₁(e)n-tér (“between”) (see above 4). NB: cf. a) *down*, b) *between, zwischen*, *inzwischen*, *unter der Woche*

Comment: long story short, WT is a poor (in this case inadmissable) source, regular readers are not qualified to understand the theory (including the present answer, comments, mine too, and many of the WT editors who are *students* who simply copy from books like yeah, sounds good!) but in fact, particles, univerbations, preverbs etc. are among (ha!) the most complicated and perhaps most important aspects for a comparative etymologist. ardly anyone is manic enough to tackle eg. George E. Dunkel: Luvian *-TAR* and Homeric *Tʼ "AP* (with further references to Watkins, etc. even Grimm; the P is AGr. Rho)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Etymology:**

New High German: *»unter«*
Middle High German: *»under«*
Old High German: *»untar«*
Proto-Germanic: *»under«*
Proto-Indoeuropean: *»ndhar«*

The Proto-Germanic word has its origin in two different etymological roots:

1. A word meaning *»between«, »among«* that is related to the following words: latin *»intĕr«* (between, among, during), Greek *»ἔντερα«* (*»éntera«*) (Intestines), Sanskrit *»antár«* or *»ántaraḥ«* (the inner, the nearer, inside, between), Old Russian *»utrь«* (inside, into).
2. A word meaning *»below«* that is related to these words: Latin *»infĕr«, »infĕrus«* (below, underneath, lower, vile, from the hell), Sanskrit *»adhah«* (below) and possibly Greek *»ἀθερίζειν«* (*»atherízein«*) (disdain, despise, spurn).

You will notice that Latin had two words that are already very similar (*»intĕr«/»infĕr«*) and that the Sanskrit words are also similar. And this can only mean that the meanings *below* and *among* were also always perceived by people as similar meanings.

When German and English were dialects of the same language, this common word was used in both languages in both meanings. But when English and German moved away from each other, only in German both meanings survived, while in English the meaning *»between«, »among«* became extinct.

---

**In other Germanic languages:**

English: *»under«*, Swedish: *»under«*, Dutch *»onder«*, Old Frisian *»under«*, Old Norse *»undir«*, Gothic: *»undar«*

---

**Usage in German:**

The word *»unter«* can be used as a preposition, an adverb, and an adjective:

- preposition

  > Der Brief liegt **unter** dem Buch.
  > <sup>*The letter is **under** the book.*</sup>
  > Paul will immer **unter** den Tisch kriechen.
  > <sup>*Paul always wants to crawl **under** the table.*</sup>
  > **Unter** den Anwesenden war keine einzige Frau.
  > <sup>*There was not a single woman **among** those present.*</sup>
  > Die Räuber teilten die Beute **unter** sich auf.
  > <sup>*The robbers divided the loot **among** themselves.*</sup>
  > Heinrich muss **unter** der Woche immer füher aufstehen als am Wochenende.
  > <sup>*Heinrich always has to get up earlier **during** the week than on weekends.*</sup>
  > Als Chef der Abteilung hat Walter 14 Leute **unter** sich.
  > <sup>*As head of the department, Walter has 14 people **under** him.*</sup>
  > Helga gebar **unter** Schmerzen einen Sohn.
  > <sup>*Helga gave birth to a son **in** pain.*</sup>
  > Die Geraden scheiden einander **unter** einem Winkel von 60 Grad.
  > <sup>*The lines cross each other **at** an angle of 60 degrees.*</sup>
  > Nicht Anfassen! Die Metallteile stehen alle **unter Strom**!
  > <sup>*Do not touch! The metal parts are all **electrified**!*</sup>
  > Die Feinde nahmen das ganze Dorf **unter** Beschuss.
  > <sup>*The enemies took the whole village **under** fire.*</sup>
  > Warum hast du das Haus **unter** seinem Wert verkauft?
  > <sup>*Why did you sell the house **below** its value?*</sup>
- adverb (only in combination with cardinal numbers)

  > Die Temperatur liegt **unter** 4 Grad.
  > <sup>*The temperature is **below** 4 degrees.*</sup>
  > Kein Eintritt für Personen **unter** 18 Jahren!
  > <sup>*No entry for people **under** 18 years!*</sup>
- adjective

  > Das Hemd liegt in der **unteren** Schublade.
  > <sup>*The shirt is in the **bottom** drawer.*</sup>
  > Jürgen ist noch in der **untersten** Gehaltsstufe.
  > <sup>*Jürgen is still in the **lowest** pay grade.*</sup>